# Windows failover cluster - virtual node with multiple Client Access Names

Tags: cluster, failovercluster, windows-cluster

I recently encountered a customer environment in which they had failover cluster where one of the virtual nodes had more than one 'Client Access Name' (i.e. more than one IP address and DNS name for the single virtual node).

Long story short we had to modify our software to deal with this situation, but we want to recreate the situation in house to test it before releasing.

I have been unable to locate any information about how or why you would end up with a virtual node that has more than one access name.

Does anyone know how I can set up a Windows failover cluster where a virtual node has more than one access name/IP?

Comment: You may want to clarify the term "virtual node", that's not really a standard failover clustering term.  Normally CAPs are associated with a service or are for general cluster administration, are these CAPs associated with SQL or with some other service or do you mean multiple CAPs for the cluster itself?  One reason to have multiple CAPs for say a clustered file server is if one is performing some sort of migration, combining previously multiple servers into one.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment on the question, it depends somewhat on what you mean by "virtual node" and whether the CAPs are for administration of the cluster itself or for some clustered service such as file sharing or SQL Server.

One reason to have multiple CAPs for a service is if it is being used to consolidate what were previously multiple servers, e.g. combining multiple file servers into a new single clustered file server.  Instructions on setting up multiple CAPs for a clustered file server are available on the [Windows Server Core Team blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2010/08/24/using-multiple-client-access-points-cap-in-a-windows-server-2008-r2-failover-cluster.aspx).